# Pinescript Code for Number of day between HIGHEST BAR from 252 days to Last BAR on Chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want number of days (if on daily chart, weeks on weekly and months on monthly chart) between HIGHEST BAR from last 252 days to LAST BAR.

Please help how to get it.

Comment: Number of bars will also do.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `ta.highestbars()` function will return the offset to the highest bar in a specified period:

```
//@version=5
indicator("highestbars")
bars = ta.highestbars(high, 252)
plot(math.abs(bars))
```

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dhighestbars

> Highest value offset for a given number of bars back.

Comment: Thanks e2e4, how to get the same after lastbar

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get you, there are no bars to the right after lastbar - it's the last one.

Comment: How to get ta.highestbars of index NIFTY close of 252 bars

Comment: You have the example above, just open the required chart. If it was not what you are looking for, please refer to the article [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Instead of just providing the requirements for your script, show us what you got and where you are stuck at. This is not a code-writing service.