# Tradingview pine script Extreme from specified time range

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-editor

I'm working on a script to show the extremes (highest high and lowest low) from a specific time range, for example last X days, or between two timestamp inputs.

I want to get a single value for high and low that I can plot as a horizontal line on a chart.

All I was able to achieve was a series of local extremes, but not a single value.

Comment: Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75447399/5577188)

Comment: @Gu5tavo71 It almost works, however highestbars function returns offset relative to previous lowest price, so I get different values across the range.